# Updating a text in the terminal instead of printing out a new line of text

Tags: ruby

My script prints out progress in the console:

```
Progress 1%
Progress 2%
Progress 3%
...
```

How do I update the text `Progress d%` in the terminal so that it's only one line and only the value of progress changes?

Comment: Are you using a particular gem for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some sample code that updates using carriage returns (`\r`):

```
100.times do |x|
  print "\rProgress #{x}%"
  sleep 0.05
end
```

I'm sure you can adapt this concept to work in your script.

Comment: You can replace the printf with an ordinary print.